# jupyter notebook - open target ipynb in browser instead of dashboard

Tags: jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It used to be the case that running `jupyter notebook my-notebook.ipynb` would launch jupyter server, launch the default browser, and navigate directly to my-notebook.ipynb, [as documented.](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html#how-do-i-open-a-specific-notebook)

Now this same command seems to only load the dashboard in the browser and the user must additionally:

- find the desired notebook in the directory listing
- open the notebook

Is there a way to have the notebook open directly?

In case it's relevant I'm running WSL v1 with Ubuntu 20.04 distribution. Ultimately my use case is to enable users to double-click a notebook in Windows File Explorer and be taken to the notebook in-browser, via a handler.